# Call a (yes/no) function to determine if user enters valid input

Tags: c

I'm trying to call a yes/no function to see if user enters valid input which is 'Y' 'y' 'N' 'n' in this case. But I don't want the two new lines between output as you can see from following attached image.

[image: Incorrect Part]

clearKeyboard function:
void clearKeyboard(void)

```
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

Yes/No function:

```
int yes(void)
{
    int result, done = 1;
    char c = 0, charenter;

    scanf("%c%c", &charenter, &c);

    while (done == 1) {
        if (c != '\n' || (!(charenter == 'Y' || charenter == 'y' || charenter == 'N' || charenter == 'n'))) {
            clearKeyboard();
            printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>: ");
            scanf("%c%c", &charenter, &c);
        }
        else {
            done = 0;
        }
    }

    if (charenter == 'Y' || charenter == 'y')
        result = 1;
    else if (charenter == 'N' || charenter == 'n')
        result = 0;

    return result;
}
```

Function to call yes/no function: I've tried remove the fflush(stdin); or leave a space before %c, none of them worked. But the "home phone number" part works fine without giving me new lines/ Invalid input error.

```
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers) // getNumbers function definition
{
    char answer;
    int result;

    printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers->cell);

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    result = yes();
    while (result == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->home);
        break;
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &answer);
    result = yes();
    while (result == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->business);
        break;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` is implementation defined/undefined -- don't use it, it doesn't do what you think it does. When you enter `y` or `n`, you actually enter `y\n` or `n\n` (the newline results from pressing `[Enter]`) You must remove it (and any other extraneous characters) from the input buffer after each input. (or use `fgets` as is recommended). What if you enter `"yes"` or `"no"` or `"hell yes I want to continue!"` You must handle each case.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks again. I actually only put fflush there to test if it works. I call yes() function there, so I assume it'll do clearkeyboard when input is invalid. Input is valid as shown in the image, it's giving me new lines because I didn't clear buffer?
Also, I didn't put clearkeyboard() in " else done = 0; is because it also gives a new line.

Comment: My apology for bad English, lemme know if you dont get what I'm saying :(

Comment: You clear `stdin` with a simple function, e.g. `void empty_stdin (void) { int c = getchar(); while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) c = getchar(); }`. Then you simply call it `empty_stdin();` when you need to ... empty `stdin`.

Comment: You may find [call menu from another function](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/85835321?noredirect=1) helpful. It covers `y/n` and quite a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, I've read it. I encountered a problem that whenever the program is calling empty_stdin function, it requires me to press enter(a \n) to continue the program.

Comment: That's because you are not being a good accountant and only calling it when there are characters to be read in `stdin`. That is another reason `fgets` is recommended `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `fgets` instead of `scanf`, you have more control with
lines using `fgets`.

If you use `scanf` to read strings, I would use this function to clear the
buffer:

```
void clear_buffer(FILE *fp)
{
    int c;
    while((c=fgetc(fp)) != '\n' && c!=EOF);
}
```

and then you can do

```
char name[15];
char phone[15];
scanf("%14s", name);
clear_buffer(stdin);

scanf("%14s", phone);
clear_buffer(stdin);
```

So your `yes` function can be rewritten as:

```
int yes(const char *prompt)
{
    char line[10];
    int ret;

    do {
        printf("%s: ", prompt);
        fflush(stdout);

        ret = scanf("%9s", line);
        clear_buffer(stdin);

        if(ret == 1)
        {
            // catch entries like "yes" and "nooooooo"
            if(line[1] != 0)
                line[0] = 0;

            switch(line[0])
            {
                case 'y':
                case 'Y':
                    return 1;

                case 'n':
                case 'N':
                    return 0;

                default:
                    printf("*** INVALID ENTRY *** <Only (Y)es or (N)o are acceptable>\n");
            }
        }
    } while(ret != EOF);

    return 0;
}
```

then you can read the numbers like this:

```
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers) // getNumbers function definition
{
    int result;

    printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers->cell);
    clear_buffer(stdin);


    if(yes("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n)"))
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->home);
        clear_buffer(stdin);
    }

    if(yes("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n)"))
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->business);
        clear_buffer(stdin);
    }
}
```

btw: why are you doing this

```
while (result == 1) {
    printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers->home);
    break;
}
```

instead of

```
if (result == 1) {
    printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers->home);
}
```

That yields the same result but this is much more easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to if. My problem is now, whenever I call said clearbuffer function, the program stops there and waiting for a \n(Enter) which is not what I want.

Comment: @zxc20100123 perhaps you still have some old code that you didn't remove. Check this out: https://onlinegdb.com/rJfS98lcG this is the code I tried and it doesn't show the behaviour you are describing.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/BT10A When I entered 'yes' or 'nooooo', it should show the error messages instead of reading the first character! Other parts work fine! ty.

Comment: @zxc20100123 the change for that is minimal, see https://onlinegdb.com/rJOybDxqM at lines 28 and 29

Comment: @zxc20100123 I also updated my answer with this small change