# int function is returning ASCII special characters?

Tags: c, int

so I'm new to C and I have a program that asks for phone numbers

getInt function looks like this:

```
int getInt(void) {
    int num;
    char newline = 0;
    do {
        scanf("%d%c", &num, &newline);
        if (newline != '\n') {
            printf("*** Invalid Integer *** <Please enter an integer>: ");
            clearKeyboard();
        }
    } while (newline != '\n');
    return num;
}
```

The definition looks like this:

```
void getNumber(struct Number *num) {
    int response;

    printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
    *num->cell = getInt();

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    response = yes();

    if (response == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        *num->home = getInt();
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    response = yes();

    if (response == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        *num->business = getInt();
    }
}
```

And the main looks like this:

```
printf("Numbers: %s|%s|%s\n", contact.number.cell, contact.number.home, contact.number.business);
```

But for some reason when I enter a phone number the output goes like this:
[error ascii?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDLN8.png)

Sorry I know about the text in image but I couldn't copy paste from the debug window.

I would just like to know what could be wrong in my code and it returns ascii letters. Thank you in advance

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", &num, &newline);` if the initial part of the line isn't digits, you will never match `if (newline != '\n')`, see `man scanf` with particular attention on `"matching failure"`.

Comment: We did have a similar question 2 days ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49416699/call-a-yes-no-function-to-determine-if-user-enters-valid-input/49417123#49417123 it's extremely similar

Comment: @David C Rankin are &num, &newline guaranteed to be written in that order seeing as function argument order is not defined? Or at least evaluation of them?

Comment: Yes, in the event of a `"matching or input failure"` no further characters are read and the input buffer is unchanged eliminating the possibility that the values ever get read out of order.

Comment: Phone numbers often have leading zeros.  You must not handle directory numbers as an integer.

Comment: @Pablo yeah, they are both homework, but at least in these cases it seems like some work has been done, (unlike so many).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so it now works after looking at the similar question that @Pablo commented.
They have the following code in the answer:

```
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers) // getNumbers function definition
{
    int result;

    printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
    scanf("%s", numbers->cell);
    clear_buffer(stdin);


    if(yes("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n)"))
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->home);
        clear_buffer(stdin);
    }

    if(yes("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n)"))
    {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%s", numbers->business);
        clear_buffer(stdin);
    }
}
```

So I then proceeded to copy the same idea:

```
void getNumber(struct Number *num) {
    int response;
    printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
    scanf("%10s", num->cell); // I changed this line from:
//  *num->cell = getInt();


    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    response = yes();

    if (response == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf("%10s", num->home); // I changed this line from:
//  *num->home = getInt();
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    response = yes();

    if (response == 1) {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf("%10s", num->business); // I changed this line from:
//  *num->business = getInt();
    }
}
```

Maybe the getInt function is not suitable for the definition. I have no idea how to explain it but this works.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: If my solution worked, then the structures you are using are the same as in the other question, that means that `num->cell` is a `char` array, not an `int`, that's why `*num->cell = getInt();` doesn't work. Also it makes sense to store telephone numbers as strings, as telephone numbers might include non-digits like +, spaces and slashes to make the numbers more readable.